# Pass Element as CommandParameter from root of ElementTree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I searched a lot through Google and StackOverflow, but nothing answered my problem.

I have two Xaml Files:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Instantiate ViewModel of the MainWindow -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="viewModel"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <!-- Create the Menu of the MainWindow -->
    <custom:MainMenu Grid.Row="0"/>

    <ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager">
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

And the **MainMenu.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="{t:Translate MENU_LAYOUT_SAVE}" Command="{Binding SaveLayoutCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="{t:Translate MENU_LAYOUT_LOAD}" Command="{Binding LoadLayoutCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

And here my Problem occurs. Instead of passing the Mainwindow-object I want to pass the DockingManager `x:Name="dockingManager"` from MainWindow. But if i try to reference the object by its name it fails...

I tried the following Bindings:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dockingManager}"
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dockingManager, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

---

So how can I find and reference an Object (`dockingManager`) from the ElementTree within xaml. I want to avoid using extra code in Code-behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dockingManager, Path=.}"`.

EDIT:
The previous answer would not work. Here's a working idea...

In the Window.xaml:

```
<custom:MainMenu Grid.Row="0" Tag="{Binding ElementName=dockingManager}" />
```

In the MainMenu.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="UcMainMenu" />
...
    <MenuItem Header="{t:Translate MENU_LAYOUT_SAVE}" Command="{Binding SaveLayoutCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UcMainMenu, Path=Tag}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast replay. Also alredy tried. Fails with `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=dockingManager'. BindingExpression:Path=.; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
`

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me but looks a bit like a dirty workaround. Probably i'll keep this a while and later go the way that meilke described.

Comment: That is a workaround, and the reason is simple: if you have a UserControl that depends directly on a control outside of itself, then maybe that's not a true UserControl. The thing that you're trying to do is just not good practice, so I would strongly suggest that you try what meilke described or something similar. In general try to avoid lateral dependencies in UI (with an exception for anything involving just plain look and style, maybe) and stick to using VM data.

Comment: Just a comment for the solution that I posted: a slightly better way (not hacky) to do this would be to use a dedicated DependencyProperty (e.g. "DockingManagerDependencyProperty" in the MainMenu UserControl. 

In fact, I just thought over what I said a moment ago: that is a good practice in my opinion. Why? One of the traps of MVVM is trying to push everything into the VM. Always consider this: can you imagine an UI for your application without feature A (e.g. a static UI without docking)? If so, then feature A shouldn't be incorporated into the VM, because VM should be UI-agnostic.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
CommandParameter="{x:Reference Name=yourElementName}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using MVVM here is what you should do to come up with a slightly different solution:

- Get rid of the `CommandParameter`
- The command will trigger a callback in the `MainWindowViewModel` instance
- This callback will change some state/properties in the `MainWindowViewModel` instance
- The `DockingManager` instance reacts to that adjusted state of the `MainWindowViewModel` instance through bindings

The way you are doing it now is way too complicated. In addition to that, you are wildly mixing patterns here. MVVM tries to separate the business logic from the actual elements. You are using elements of MVVM with Smart UI/Code Behind techniques.

Also, consider using individual view models for individual controls. The main menu control is separate and the docking manager is, too. Why? Because you want to break everything into smaller pieces, but more importantly, because you might have reusability in mind. With the main menu trying to access a docking manager inside a `Window` that is not possible.

Comment: That would be more elegant, but the question was straightforward and this does not answer it.

Comment: @CodeMonkey You are absolutely right. I could not resist giving advice instead of an answer (which in fact I do not have right now).

Comment: That's understood, and I would urge user2823573 to consider using this suggestion :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on your suggetion. Whats so bad about my approach to pass `dockingManager` via binding?

Comment: @user2823573 I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @user2823573 Not bad but complicated.